# Why does my arduino code not work propely, The led dosnt act as anticepated

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

When i press the button the led turns on but faded, and then fades to black..

The code is supplsed to turn the led on at 100% at the first press of the button and fade down by 25% for each press.

I am somwhat new to arduino so some logical errors i dont understand please help me

Here is the hardware:
[image: Hardware]

```
int LED = 11;
  const int Bryter = 8;

  int LED1;
  int Bryterstat;

  int Count = 0;


void setup()
{
    pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Bryter,INPUT_PULLUP);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    LED1 = digitalRead(LED);
    Bryterstat = digitalRead(Bryter);
    delay(10);
    Serial.println(LED1);
    if (Count == 0)
    {
        analogWrite(11,0);
        Count = 5;
    }
  
    if (Bryterstat == LOW && Count == 5)
    {
        analogWrite(11,255);
        Count = 1;
    }
  
    if (Bryterstat == LOW && Count == 1)
    {
        analogWrite(11,191);
        Count = 2;
    }
  
    if (Bryterstat == LOW && Count == 2)
    {
        analogWrite(11,127);
        Count = 3;
    }
  
    if (Bryterstat == LOW && Count == 3)
    {
        analogWrite(11,255);
        Count = 4;
    }

    if (Bryterstat == LOW && Count == 4)
    {
        analogWrite(11,0);
        Count = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your program will execute all `analogWrite` lines at once when `Bryterstat == LOW` because new `Count` value after assignments matches the next `if` conditions. You should use `else if` or `switch` not to perform other checks after finding one satisfied condition.
- To do someting only once per each button press, you should check the previous button state and do that only if the button is not previously pressed.

Try this:

```
int LED = 11;
const int Bryter = 8;

int LED1;
int Bryterstat, prevBryterstat;

int Count = 0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Bryter,INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  LED1 = digitalRead(LED);
  Bryterstat = digitalRead(Bryter);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println(LED1);
  if (Count == 0)
  {
    analogWrite(11,0);
    Count = 5;
  }
  
  if (prevBryterstat != LOW && Bryterstat == LOW)
  {
    switch (Count)
    {
      case 5:
        analogWrite(11,255);
        Count = 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        analogWrite(11,191);
        Count = 2;
        break;
      case 2:
        analogWrite(11,127);
        Count = 3;
        break;
      case 3:
        analogWrite(11,255);
        Count = 4;
        break;
      case 4:
        analogWrite(11,0);
        Count = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
  prevBryterstat = Bryterstat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your code check the pressed status of your button but not the change of state of the button.

Lets' me explain more :

Your program is iterating over the loop as fast as it can. In your case around every 10ms, since you have a `delay(10)`. So when you press the button, it will detect it correctly and light the LED at 100%. But before you release the button, the loop will repeat and it will enter the second case and lower the brightness.

So it might run multiple times before you release the button. And that why you get a dimmed light.

To resolve this you need to detect a change in the button status and not only the status itself. We call this an edge (rising edge or falling edge).

You have a good tutorial explaining this on [arduino website](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/digital/StateChangeDetection).